# Exception : This publisher does not support multiple subscribers (spring data r2dbc + oracle-r2dbc)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-r2dbc

## Exception

'''
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Failed to obtain R2DBC Connection; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: This publisher does not support multiple subscribers.
at org.springframework.r2dbc.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.lambda$getConnection$0(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:88) ~[spring-r2dbc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.lambda$onErrorMap$31(Mono.java:3676) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]'''

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.database.r2dbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>oracle-r2dbc</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: POM file attached

Comment: Trying to connect to oracle with r2dbc. Pls help

Comment: Do not mix code with xml please. And, you could try setting the properties in `application.yml|properties` instead of creating the Bean manually

Comment: Thanks @grekier I tried all the combination but at the end I am getting =>This publisher does not support multiple subscribers.

Comment: spring.r2dbc.username=usernname
spring.r2dbc.password=dxh7CumV
spring.r2dbc.url=r2dbc:oracle://hostname:389/dbname
spring.r2dbc.pool.initial-size=2
spring.r2dbc.pool.max-size=10

Comment: @guys ...appreciate ur suggestions

Comment: @umeshkaran can u find out the solution for your problem? I'm facing it too.

Comment: In my case, the credentials to connect to the database were incorrect. so I changed the credentials. Now its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a [bug](https://github.com/oracle/oracle-r2dbc/issues/29) in Oracle R2DBC which prevents it to work with a connection pool.